# Why do unitary transformations on ensembles of states result in the same density matrix?

Tags: density-operator, unitarity

This is from Nielsen and Chuang. If we have an ensemble of pure states that obey the following relationship for all $i, j$

$\vert \psi_i \rangle = \sum_{j} u_{ij}\vert \phi_j \rangle$

where $u_{ij}$ corresponds to the entries of a unitary matrix, we will obtain the same density matrix for both. That is, we will have

$\rho = \sum_{i}\vert \psi_i \rangle\langle \psi_i \vert = \sum_{i}\vert \phi_i \rangle\langle \phi_i \vert$

The proof is straightforward and given in the book but I have no idea what the correct way to interpret this result is. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what is this 'both' you're referring to here ? The original and the tranformed matrix?

Comment: Can you suggest the exact page no. from Nielsen and Chuang

Comment: This is theorem 2.6 (unitarity freedom in the ensemble for density matrices). It's page 103 in my edition but might be different in yours.

Comment: Equal energy and volume does not imply parallel transport. That is their unities are unique. Unitary ensembles can represent the same system in two different configurations i.e 6D Boltzmann space-time however are still subject to identical normalization.

Comment: Sorry, I've literally no idea what you're saying.